# Wildcard to match files with two "dots"

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, windows-shell

This does not work:

```
del "folder\*.dll.config"
```

However, it does work without specifying a folder

```
cd folder
del "*.dll.config"
```

Why?

PS. Also, any workarounds? (beside the one mentioned - changing current dir and then going back)

EDIT: I'm an idiot I had a typo in my code, voting to close my own question now.

Comment: It works fine for me, do you get an error?

Comment: yes, "the system cannot find file specicifed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Windows 10, it works:

```
C:\>dir folder
Volume in drive C is SYSTEM
Directory of C:\folder

30.03.2017  14.33    <DIR>          .
30.03.2017  14.33    <DIR>          ..
29.03.2017  13.33           549.341 my.dll.config
29.03.2017  13.33           549.341 my.foo.bar
           2 File(s)      1.098.682 bytes
           2 Dir(s) 363.317.178.368 bytes free

C:\>del "folder\*.dll.config"

C:\>dir folder
Volume in drive C is SYSTEM
Directory of C:\folder

30.03.2017  14.33    <DIR>          .
30.03.2017  14.33    <DIR>          ..
29.03.2017  13.33           549.341 my.foo.bar
           1 File(s)        549.341 bytes
           2 Dir(s) 363.317.809.152 bytes free

C:\>
```

However, your misspelling of the error message in the comment above made me check something.

It may be completely irrelevant in your case, but sure enough, if I misspell the folder name, I get precisely the error you mentioned:

```
C:\>dir folder
Volume in drive C is SYSTEM
Directory of C:\folder

30.03.2017  14.33    <DIR>          .
30.03.2017  14.33    <DIR>          ..
29.03.2017  13.33           549.341 my.dll.config
29.03.2017  13.33           549.341 my.foo.bar
           2 File(s)      1.098.682 bytes
           2 Dir(s) 363.317.248.000 bytes free

C:\>del "dolder\*.dll.config"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\>
```

Comment: No, you're not an idiot. We've all made similar mistakes and (hopefully) learned from them: When the computer complains about a command, always first check your spelling!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the`pushd` and `popd` commands like:

```
 pushd folder
 del "*.dll.config"
 popd
```

This way you move to the desire location, erase all `.dll.config` files and return to the previous location.